# Condition expected - can't figure out why

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query but it's not working. I want to see only one `studentname` because `dated` is unique.

```sql
SELECT r.classteacher,
  r.studentname,
  r.reggroup,
  r.yeargroup,
  rrl.cdated 
FROM [dbo].[Reports] AS r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN reportsreadlog AS rrl
  ON r.rguid = rrl.creportguid
WHERE
  (
    SELECT TOP(1) r.studentname
    FROM [dbo].[Reports] AS r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN reportsreadlog AS rrl
      ON r.rguid = rrl.creportguid
    WHERE r.periodguid = '4390dc5f-eb21-4673-83f0-e7f973524916'
  )
  AND r.periodguid = '4390dc5f-eb21-4673-83f0-e7f973524916' 
GROUP BY r.classteacher,
  r.studentname,
  r.reggroup,
  r.yeargroup,
  rrl.cdated
ORDER BY  r.reggroup
```

Current result when I fix the error:

```
classteacher | studentname | reggroup | yeargroup | cdate
-------------+-------------+----------+-----------+------
Teacher 1    | Student 1   | class    | year      | dated
Teacher 1    | Student 1   | class    | year      | dated
Teacher 1    | Student 1   | class    | year      | dated
```

Desired result:

```
classteacher | studentname | reggroup | yeargroup | cdate
-------------+-------------+----------+-----------+------
Teacher 1    | Student 1   | class    | year      | dated
Teacher 1    | Student 2   | class    | year      | dated
Teacher 1    | Student 3   | class    | year      | dated
```

Comment: Can you add factually and expected result example?

Comment: Well, the first part of your `WHERE` clause is just a `SELECT` :..... in the `WHERE` clause, you need to have **conditions**, e.g. checking a value is greater than 0 or something - just a `SELECT` which doesn't check anything isn't a valid **condition** - what are you trying to do with that `SELECT TOP(1) :...` ????

Comment: Can you post the Error you're getting or a data set example? This is very vague

Comment: TOP 1 without ORDER BY?

Comment: GROUP BY without any set functions? Simply want SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'. I have also added the desired and current result,maybe im thinking the wrong way now.

Comment: You don't compare the subquery result to anything.

Comment: The error is because the first predicate in your where clause makes no sense. You have half of an expression there. But it also seems to be completely unnecessary to have a subquery there. You are hitting the same tables as the main query. Perhaps you need to provide a [mcve] so we can understand the issue and help you find a solution.

Comment: It looks to me like the subquery in the `where` might possibly be prefixed by `EXISTS`?

Comment: My idea was, to pick the top1 studentname , because i cant get rid of the cdated column because otherwise i cant see if the report is read or not. Thats why i used the left outer join. Because i also want to know if someone didnt read the report.

Comment: *I want to see only one `studentname`* - remove all columns from `GROUP BY` clause instead of `studentname`.

Answer (score 0):

Without table definitions and sample/test data, its kind of hard to answer your question. So, please update your post to add them to assist further.

Meanwhile, please try below:

```
SELECT distinct r.classteacher,
  r.studentname,
  r.reggroup,
  r.yeargroup,
  rrl.cdated 
FROM [dbo].[Reports] AS r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN reportsreadlog AS rrl
  ON r.rguid = rrl.creportguid
WHERE r.periodguid = '4390dc5f-eb21-4673-83f0-e7f973524916' --Based on my understanding you don't need other subquery condition here.
--    GROUP BY r.classteacher,
--      r.studentname,
--      r.reggroup,
--      r.yeargroup,
--      rrl.cdated
    ORDER BY  r.reggroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping out. In the end i gave up and did it the ugly way.

Ran the query twice and combined the results
Once and rrl.cdated is null and after that and rrl.cdated is not null